# Problem converting RTSP to HLS Nginx to stream

Tags: nginx, streaming, rtsp, rtmp, http-live-streaming

I'm really new with *nginx* and *Ubuntu*. I'm trying to setup a website to stream an IP Camera Video to the internet. I'm currently using `nginx 1.14` and `ubuntu 18.04`.

I have the *RTSP url* from the camera and succeed converting it in RTMP with `ffmpeg` inside my `nginx.conf` file. I can play the video (both the RTSP and RTMP urls) in VLC without problems.

My main problem is when I want to convert RTMP to HLS so can play it in a html5 player (like `videojs`) it doesn't work. Please, see my code below.

### nginx.conf

```bsh
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

rtmp {
    server {
        listen 1935;
        chunk_size 4096;
        
        application live {
            live on;
            record off;
            hls on;
            hls_nested on;
            hls_path /tmp/hls/;
            hls_fragment 3;
            hls_playlist_length 60;
            exec_pull /usr/bin/ffmpeg -i rtsp://025164132:jose1992@192.168.0.16:554/onvif1 -vcodec libx264 -acodec copy -f flv rtmp://192.168.0.14:1935/live/stream1;
        }   
    }
}

http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;

    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # SSL Settings
    ##

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;

    # gzip_vary on;
    # gzip_proxied any;
    # gzip_comp_level 6;
    # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    # gzip_http_version 1.1;
    # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;

    server {     
        listen    80;

        location /hls {
            # Serve HLS fragments

            # Disable cache
            add_header 'Cache-Control' 'no-cache';

            # CORS setup
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' always;
            add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Content-Length';

            # allow CORS preflight requests
            if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
                add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
                add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain charset=UTF-8';
                add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
                return 204;
            }

            types {
                application/dash+xml mpd;
                application/vnd.apple.mpegurl m3u8;
                video/mp2t ts;
            }
            root /tmp/;
        }

        location / {
            root   html;
            index  index.html index.htm;
        }

        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }
    }
}
```

So, when I try to open this url `http://ip-server/hls/stream1.m3u8` on a browser or VLC instance nothing happens.

I verified that the `.ts` and the `.m3u8` files are being created each time that *nginx* is running in the folder `tmp/hls/stream1/` (`ts` and a `index.m3u8`) I don't know why the `m3u8` file is named `index` instead of `stream1`.

Please, if you could help me and correct any of my code if needed. I have been trying for 3 days for this to work but with no luck :(

Thanks!